# How to ping a network host at regular intervals?

Tags: ping

I am trying to debug WiFi connectivity issues on my home network. I have a Macbook and a Linux desktop client. I would like to run ping on both machines and compare their results. I am comfortable with Linux, this question is exclusively about the Macbook.

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1 | while read pong; do echo "[$(date +%s)] $pong"; done
...
[1596203814] 64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=8900 ttl=64 time=9.800 ms
[1596203815] 64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=8901 ttl=64 time=5.546 ms
[1596205241] Request timeout for icmp_seq 8902
[1596205241] 64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=8903 ttl=64 time=26.988 ms
[1596205242] 64 bytes from 192.168.1.254: icmp_seq=8904 ttl=64 time=4.397 ms
...
```

As you can see from the timestamps there is a 20+ minutes gap at some point. I let the setup run for 3 hours and this happened on 5 different occasions. The Macbook was locked with Amphetamine running, the lid was closed but an external display was connected through a USB-C hub with HDMI output. I do not believe the Macbook can go to sleep under these circumstances.

Would anyone please know how I can fix my setup to ping at regular intervals, without any large gap?

Comment: The 20 minutes gap is hard to see with the chosen date format (check the `--apple-time` option), but it seems to happen at the same time the request timed out. Does the gap and a timeout always occur together? If you run a `while sleep 10; do date; done` loop in a separate window, does it get interrupted at the same moments as the ping loop?

Comment: Just run the same command in a second terminal but with echo instead of ping. Then you will see if the gap is caused by network or system.

Comment: Flooding your network with ICMP packets is not a way to debug WiFi issues.  You need a proper network analyzer.  The problem eith this, is when a device is dealing with legitimate traffic (i.e. the apps on your Mac updating) your ping may get delayed causing you to believe theres a network issue where theres none.

Comment: @Allan, you are correct generally speaking, but the output of ping is a good enough proxy in my case. And I left my network analyzer in my other pants :)

Comment: @nohillside, thanks for your contribution. I used that date format because it's easier to parse. I should have said but the gaps and timeouts always happen together, and all the ping processes running in parallel are impacted simultaneously. Anyway it's solved: the Macbook was going to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Macbook was locked with Amphetamine running, the lid was closed but an external display was connected through a USB-C hub with HDMI output. I do not believe the Macbook can go to sleep under these circumstances.

I wouldn't be so sure. Just check the output of `pmset -g log | grep "Display is turned off"` - if it happened when the ping got interrupted, you Mac went to sleep. I find Macbooks particularly stubborn when the charger is disconnected.
Also note that if the external display was turned off, or switched to another input, this can also be sometimes detected (depends on model/connection, I assume), so this could also trigger the sleep.

There's no magic switch to `ping` to issue  echo requests regularly - it does that by default.

Comment: Great answer thanks. The charger was connected, but I switched the input source on the monitor and that was the problem. It's working if I leave the lid open.